# NodeJS: Code optimization and variable scoping

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

Really new to pure Javascript programming and I was just wondering how I could optimize redundant codes below:

```
module.exports = function(app, express) {
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        var db = req.db;
        var collection = db.get('projects');
        var projects = collection.find({}, {}, function(e, docs){
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message : 'ok',
                projects: docs
            });
        });
    });

    router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
        var db = req.db;
        var collection = db.get('projects');
        var projects = collection.find({_id: req.params.id}, {}, function(e, docs){
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message : 'ok',
                project: docs
            });
        });
    });

    return router;
};
```

As you can see codes starting at `var db`  up to the `res.json()` block are optimizable but I'm not sure how I could proceed with it. Any ideas , guys?

Thanks!

Comment: Its not necessary to define db variable on each request, You can simply define it in the head of your code, after/before this line var ```router = express.Router()``` , Also you can use http://mongoosejs.com/, which provide many usefull features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function to deliver the results of a query back to a client:

```
function handleQuery(query, req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('projects');
    var projects = collection.find(query, {}, function(e, docs){
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message : 'ok',
            project: docs
        });
    });
}
```

Then your routes can collapse to these:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    handleQuery({}, req, res, next);
});

router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    handleQuery({_id: req.params.id}, req, res, next);
});
```

While you’re at it, realize that you’re not correctly handling errors. To correctly handle errors, you should inspect the value of `e`. If it is truthy, you have an error, and you need to handle it appropriately, e.g. like so:

```
function handleQuery(query, req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('projects');
    var projects = collection.find(query, {}, function(e, docs){
        if(e) {
            return next(e);
        }
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message : 'ok',
            project: docs
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: So far this solution goes with what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your validation in these controllers

Instead of using this every time:

```js
 res.json({
   success: true,
   message: 'ok',
   project: docs
 });
```

you can extend your "res" object  and keep doing in this way.

```js
res.ok({
  project: docs
});
```

Also I cannot find error verification. if you get an error in the process of querying to database you should respond a client with another status.

```js
function(err, docs){
   if ( err ){
      return res.serverError(err);  // extend in  res object
   }
   ...
}
```

And one more important thing. If you have many routes your file will be unreadable (file will be too big, and it will be difficult to change it). 
So my advice is to separate controller and an action. Each controller should be in separated file.

So, as a result, you'll get something like this:

```js
 router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        var db = req.db;
        var collection = db.get('projects');
        var projects = collection.find({}, {}, function(err, docs){
            if(err){
              return res.serverError(err);
            }

            return res.ok({
                projects: docs
            });
        });
    });
```

```js
 router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
       var id = req.params.id;
       ControllerName.validate(id, function(err, result){
           if(err){
               return next();
           }

           var db = req.db;
           var collection = db.get('projects');
           var projects = collection.find({_id: id}, {}, function(err, docs){
               if(err){
                   return res.serverError(err);
               }

               return res.ok({
                    project: docs
               });
           });
       });
 });
```

You could also use Promise for more readible.

Comment: I still can see a lot of redundant codes. Any way I could make the process more modular?

Comment: Still forgot to address the redundant code issue but I learned a lot from your answer. I'm giving you a +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = function(app, express) {
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get(['/', '/:id'], function (req, res, next) {
        var db = req.db;
        var collection = db.get('projects');
        var search = req.params.id ? {id: req.params.id} : {}
        var projects = collection.find(search, {}, function(e, docs){
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message : 'ok',
                projects: docs
            });
        });
    });

    return router;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Not a generic solution but I learned something new from it. Much appreciated. [:thumbsup]

Comment: I suggest you to read whole express documentation, it's simple and not long, very good for beginners in web server on node